# Displaying a Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm encountering a problem with displaying data from the linked list. I have tried to both include the display loop inside my for loop and out just to check whether it was a problem with pointers and data but I've been getting the same result.

It displays the first data but then starts showing gibberish.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void main(void) {
    clrscr();
    struct Student {
        string Name;
        double GPA;
        Student *next;
    };

    Student *head;
    head = NULL;

    int ch, i;
    string name;
    double gpa;

    cout << "How Many Records Do You Want To Enter?";
    cin >> ch;
    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < ch; i++) {
        cout << (i + 1) << ". Name Of Student:";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "GPA Of Student:";
        cin >> gpa;
        cout << endl;

        Student *newstudent;
        Student *studentptr;

        newstudent = new Student;
        newstudent->Name = name;
        newstudent->GPA = gpa;
        newstudent->next = NULL;

        if (!head)
            head = newstudent;
        else {
            studentptr = head;

            while (studentptr->next) {
                studentptr = studentptr->next;
            }
            studentptr->next = new Student;
        }
    }

    clrscr();
    Student *display;
    display = head;

    while (display) {
        cout << "Name:" << display->Name << endl;
        cout << "GPA:" << display->GPA << endl;

        display = display->next;
    }
    getch();
}
```

Any suggestions and pointers towards the right direction?

Apparently I was following someone's tutorial but this error occurs.

Comment: Please change `void main` to `int main`

Comment: Two comments: (1) learn to initialize pointers on declaration, thereby turning their indeterminate time period to near-zero; (c) **Always** check your stream operations for success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`studentptr->next = new Student;` should be `studentptr->next = newstudent;`

Comment: And now I'm officially feeling like a retard, seriously thanx mate. My head hasn't been in the correct place and I seriously went through the code a hundred times before posting it here.

Comment: @MajorAly happens to all of us - sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes!

Comment: @Rollie Thanx for an optimistic line needed that I guess :D

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is about suggestions in the right direction:

1. You need to **always** check that you input was successful after you attempted to read whatever you want to read, e.g., `if (std::cin >> value) { ... }`.
2. [Do not use `std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/).
3. You are creating an excess `Student` object in your loop.
4. You are not hooking up the created `Student` object with the list. You probably meant to do this where you create a new object instead.

Comment: I'm actually getting back my concepts so I'm just writing up code like rookie and not actually caring about the consequences for the moment. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions that may help:

```
struct Student {
    string Name;
    double GPA;
    Student *next;
    Student(const string& name, double GPA) : Name(name), GPA(GPA), next(NULL) {}
    void print() {
        cout << "Name:" << Name << endl;
        cout << "GPA:" << GPA << endl;
    }
};
```

now instead of:

```
    newstudent = new Student;
    newstudent->Name = name;
    newstudent->GPA = gpa;
    newstudent->next = NULL;
```

You simply write:

```
newstudent = new Student(name, gpa);
```

Make a struct for the list:

```
struct StudentList {
    Student* head;
    Student* current;

    StudentList() :head(NULL), current(NULL) {}

    ~StudentList() {/*Delete list here*/}

    void insert(string name, double gpa) {
        if(!head) {
            head = new Student(name, gpa);
            current = head;
        } else {
            current->next = new Student(name, gpa);
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    void display() {
        Student *display = head;
        while (display) {
            display->print();
            display = display->next;
        }
    }
};
```

With all this your main should now be:

```
int main(void) {
    clrscr();

    StudentList list;

    int ch, i;
    string name;
    double gpa;

    cout << "How Many Records Do You Want To Enter?";
    cin >> ch;
    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < ch; i++) {
        cout << (i + 1) << ". Name Of Student:";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "GPA Of Student:";
        cin >> gpa;
        cout << endl;

        list.insert(name, gpa);
    }

    clrscr();
    list.display();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Interesting, shows how much I have forgotten. Thanx for the suggestion, will definitely get me better again.